# What SonarQube plugins support SSO?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube, single-sign-on, sonarqube-ops

I see "Authentication and authorization can also be delegated to an external system: LDAP or Active Directory with the SonarQube LDAP Plugin, PAM with the SonarQube PAM Plugin or Crowd with the SonarQube Crowd Plugin. SSO is also supported through the SonarQube OpenID plugin" in [SonarQube documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Security)

It seems that only SonarQube OpenID plugin supports SSO.

But I see about Active Directory plugin: "It automatically logs in user using Single Sign On (SSO) with Active Directory Credentials in Microsoft Active Directory Environments." [here](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory).

Also "the LDAP plugin now supports Single Sign On (SSO)" from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/11/13/support-for-active-directory-and-single-sign-on-sso-in-the-sonarqube-ldap-plugin/).

My questions:

1. Do Active Directory plugin or SonarQube LDAP Plugin supports SSO?
2. Crowd plugin do not support SSO, right?
3. Can I use Crowd plugin + some another plugin or tool to support SSO (For example OpenId plugin+Crowd plugin, LDAP Plugin+Crowd plugin)?

I use Crowd to authentificate my services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use SSO with SonarQube, you can use the following plugins : 
- [GitHub Authentication Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Authentication+Plugin).
- [Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-aad)
- [Bitbucket Authentication Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-bitbucket)

It's also possible to use the [Active Directory Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory), but it's not compatible with SonarQube 6.X.

The last version of the [LDAP](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) Plugin doesn't support SSO.

AFAIK, it's not possible for the moment to use SSO with Crowd.

In 6.2, there will also have the possibility to use HTTP headers in order have SSO. See the [JIRA ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5430) for more details about that.

Comment: i know it's been a long time since this post was created but how safe it is to setup this plugin ?

Comment: @IgorBieńkowski which plugin are you talking about ?

Comment: @IgorBieńkowski ok then I would recommend you to post another thread to specifically ask about it. This plugin is not provided by SonarSource so on my side I cannot guarantee the safety of it.

Comment: Is there any SSO plugin which uses JWT

Comment: @UmeshKumar What is exactly your need?  Because SonarQube is using JWT by default

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam I am looking for an option which will support Sonarqube to use JWT based authentication

Comment: @UmeshKumar Then as I said, SonarQube is already using JWT during authentication